# Which OLS assumptions should I test for given a log-log functional form?

Tags: econometrics, statistics

For a log-log functional form ( e.g. most simply: ln(y) = β1 + β2ln(x) ), which OLS assumptions should I test for (that is, test if they've been violated)? For example, I'm assuming that I *wouldn't* need to test for non-linearity (as the log transformation generates the desired linearity in parameters). However, I also assume that I won't need to carry out a test for *every* single assumption. So at this stage, I'm thinking that I only need to carry out tests for i) heteroskedasticity, ii) endogeneity and iii) multicollinearity? So I'm also assuming (maybe wrongly) that I don't need to test for the other assumptions like autocorrelation (because it's not a time series regression) or normality.

To be clear, I'm cautious about testing everything because we were told:

> Do not estimate models or conduct tests unless you are sure that they help you to carry out the tasks required by the assignment

And we have 2,500 words, so I'm thinking its not necessary to test for all OLS assumptions. Am I correct in assuming this?

Comment: You should decide which assumptions to test based on your course. For example, even with cross sectional regression you have to test for autocorrelation as even in cross section there might be spatial autocorrelation. Moreover, there can be always some problem with non normal errors and not all forms of non-linearity can be solved by log linearization and so on but in class you are supposed to do what is expected based on the contents of the course - if you did not covered spatial autocorrelation then probably you don’t need to check for it.

Comment: @1muflon1 Hm, in that case, I think I don't need to include it as we weren't taught how to test for autocorrelation w/ cross-sectional data. Thanks for the response. If you don't mind me asking one more thing: what does it mean that "your preferred functional form should be _augmented_ to test whether being located in the northern region has any association with output" (details incl. for context). I'm just confused what 'augment' means, although I assume it has something to do with accommodating for a dummy variable they give for region (north vs south). But idk how that works at all.

Comment: augmented just means that your model should be expanded to include the test for that